# Having trouble building Qt program

Tags: c++, qt, dll, runtime, distribute

I created a Qt GUI application and I am trying to package it to share with other people. I built the package and used Dependency Walker to find all of the .dll files that I needed to include. After I put them all in the same directory as the .exe; I launched the .exe for the program and I got a message that another .dll was missing I included it. I was asked in the same way to add two more .dll files. After all the .dll's were included I launched the .exe and got this weird message.

[image: Error message]

I consulted Qt 5.0.2 documentation and I couldn't find any help. It works fine when I run it within Qt Creator.

I don't know what to do from here but any help would be great

Comment: it is related to Microsoft Visual C++ Run-time Library, msvcr***.dll

Comment: and make sure you built it in release mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things you could do to find out the problem:

- Check if it behave the same way in debug and release mode. Note that the two modes need different DLLs.
- Check if you are using the correct versions of the DLLs. If you installed different versions of Qt or other dependencies than there could be conflicts around DLLs that are the same but from different versions. Maybe you are in a kind of [DLL Hell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_Hell).
- You should copy your program to another PC that doesn't have Qt installed. And watch if it works properly.